# What does it mean when a data size is return from du command for "./"?

Tags: linux, disk-usage

I had some directories fill with data much more quickly than I expected during an `rsync` between two servers. When I ran `du` to see where my large files were, I got an entry for "./" with a data size.

```
$ du -a . | sort -nr
43183048        .
16273188        ./
16272884        ./2016-template-disk1.vmdk
```

Comment: What do you get with `ls -aQ`? It looks like you have a file whose name is whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, it's something like clusters or something, so very dependent on your HD layout. Just use `-h` for human readable.